# Random variables and co-variance, Statistics 318

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, covariance, variance

For the given example in the book

> John E. Freund's Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 8th edition, by Miller and Miller. ISBN: 9780321807090

I've highlighted using colors what numbers corespond with what is given (Blue, Green, and Yellow).

What I don't understand is where the highlighted **red** numbers come from.

[image: Example 19]

The example states it uses "Theorem 15" I'm just confused on how.

"The following is another important theorem about linear combinations of random
variables; it concerns the covariance of two linear combinations of n random
variables."
[image: Theorem 15]

Comment: You´ve comprehended the answer of parsaid within 5 seconds. Congrats.

Comment: @callculus well to be fair I continued to work through the problem and I figured it out on my own and as I was working through it I saw the answer was posted, and the answer goes along with what I figured out so I figured I would select it as answered to help others out and since it is correct. So not quite 5 seconds haha but thanks!

Comment: I was just wondering. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Define $X_{1}=X$, $X_{2}=Y$, and $X_{3}=Z$.
Also define $a_{1}=1$, $a_{2}=4$, $a_{3}=2$, $b_{1}=3$, $b_{2}=-1$, and $b_{3}=-1$. Then,
$$
\text{cov}(X+4Y+2Z,3X-Y-Z)
=\text{cov}(\underbrace{a_{1}X_{1}+a_{2}X_{2}+a_{3}X_{3}}_{Y_1},\underbrace{b_{1}X_{1}+b_{2}X_{2}+b_{3}X_{3}}_{Y_2}).
$$
The above now looks like the expression in Theorem 15. Can you finish?